# Add a reference to assembly netstandard error with .NET Framework 4.6.1 project

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

A `.NET Framework 4.6.1` project which has a reference to a nuget package built with `.netstandard2.0` is no more building. The following is the error. It is around the time when the IT Department uninstalled `.net core 2.0 SDK` from the build machine.

I added `<Reference Include="netstandard" />` to the project. The following error goes away but gives another error.

How can I fix this problem? Will installing `.net core 3.1 SDK` solve the problem?

````
26-Apr-2022 18:13:55 C:\bamboo6104\xml-data\build-dir\BAM-PF1818-JOB1\MyProject\Services\SubscriptionProvider.cs(37,41): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [C:\bamboo6104\xml-data\build-dir\BAM-PF1818-JOB1\MyProjectFolder\MyProject.csproj]```
````

Answer (score -1):

Installing **Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools** fixed the problem.